# web3.py calling smart contract function generates TypeError: call_contract_function() argument after * must be an iterable, not NoneType

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js, web3py

I am having problems calling functions in my smart contract that return values. I've tried changing my versions of Python, web3 and the Solidity smart contract but problems still occurs. Transact() functions work fine.The call() functions work in Truffle and Remix IDE.

[My connection of Truffle and Ganache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s947b.png)

[My smart contract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFxaf.png)

[Calling the function and error generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1kBh.png)

Comment: Can you edit the questions and actual relevant part tot the question using Markdown text formatting, instead having them as links.